# Windows: emulate green CRT on modern LCD

Tags: windows, windows-xp, display, themes, color-profiles

I felt the old green phosphorous CRT very relaxing.

Is there any way to emulate the  monotone green of a phosphorous CRT on modern LCD monitors?

Can I solve it coding a Windows theme or monitor color profile?

Comment: I used a matrix screensaver a while ago... no quite what you are looking for, but at least you'll have the green display during breaks?!

Comment: I asking to experts which is the technical solution. IMHO know-how and opinion aren't 100% identical...

Comment: The trouble with your question is the request for that *green look & feel*. Suppose you and I remember that differently (we do); my answer will differ from what the next guy will answer based on our subjective recollection of that *look and feel*.

Comment: You could switch to the Windows Classic theme and choose the color scheme for each object type (e.g. Active Title Bar, Inactive Title Bar, 3D objects, etc).  I made a green text on dark background theme way back when using Windows XP.  A fair warning, there may be some readability issues with web browsers (and perhaps other 3rd party apps) where the background/foreground colors may not be defined by the Windows theme, but within the scope of the application itself.

Comment: @Blaelph I used the same trick, but I abandoned it for the same reasons: too much wasted time to replicate the theme settings for many applications.

Comment: I think the best option is a low level solution. Close to the graphic driver, convert from RGB to monochrome. This way I can override both windows and applications color settings.

Comment: In that case, you may be able to configure your graphics driver to display in green monochrome.  Ensure you have the latest version of the driver for your graphics card for your OS.  You can try the drivers made by your card manufacturer (e.g. Gigabyte, ASUS, MSI, etc) or also the generic ones by the GPU manufacturer (AMD/ATI, nVidia, Intel) and see if they have options to modulate the color expression output.  Good luck!